# Replace existing directory and all of its content when rpm package is installed

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I have created an rpm package and while installing it I want to replace all the existing directory and its contents with rpm package data

Let's say that I have a directory called config/ which has some config files (a.config, b.config, etc.), now `a.config` is deprecated and I don't want it anymore. So I created a new rpm package with all the files except `a.config`, but when I install the package it updates `b.config` and every other file in the directory but it doesn't delete or remove `a.config`.

I am using following command to install rpm package

```
rpm -Uvh --force package.rpm
```

I want to keep only those files and directory that are included in the package and delete other files and folders

Comment: I am using
```rpm -Uvh --force package.rpm```
to install rpm package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question,

whatever step you want to execute before rpm package installation starts, you need to define in `%pre` script in rpm spec file.

So I wrote

```
%pre
rm -f a.config
```

in my spec file and it removed the config file before rpm package installation started

Comment: IMHO you should make that `mv a.config a.config.rpmold` in case there was some configuration info the user wanted. This is assuming you were expecting the user to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

If your first `rpm` package correctly included `a.config` in the `%files` section, and it remained untouched, and was not listed in your second version of the package `%files` section, then it should be removed automatically during the upgrade process.  Your `b.config` would be the only file that remains, added during the installation of the second package.

The only way a.config would remain, is if it was never listed with %files.